# Mail Sending problem in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed an application with .Net platform. My question is: when I attempt to send an activation password  to my customer, I got the following the error.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:25

Here is my code:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="username@server.com">
    <network host="smtp.server.com" password="xxx" userName="JohnSmith" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: did you check your SMTP setup correctness ?? passowrd? username?

Comment: Could a firewall be blocking outgoing connections on port 25?

Comment: yes it can be firewall or virus scanner blocking smtp connection attempt, pls check that first

Comment: Okay,I will check my firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that smtp is active and running on that IP? I'm not able to telnet into it on port 25

Comment: +1 Telnet is a very good way to check if a smtp server is available.